# Foucault pendulum, where did I go wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

I wanted to approximate the number $N$ of periodes needed, such that the foucault pendelum turns one time. Though my result is off by the factor 2 of the results I found.

What I did: I assume the pendelum is at start in the $y'z'$ plane ($K'$ moves and turns with the earth and $K$ moves with the earth but doesnt turn), then I say the ‎oscillation behaves like $$y'=Acos(\Omega t),$$ so I'll get with the coriolis-'force' $$\ddot{x'}(t)=-2A\Omega\omega\sin\phi\sin\Omega t$$ where $\phi$ is the ‎degree of latitude and $\omega$ is the earths angular velocity. For half a period (of oscillation) I get (by integrating 2 times) $$\delta x' = -A\omega\sin\phi T.$$ Then I just calculate $$N=\frac{2\pi A}{2|\delta x'|}=\frac{\Omega}{2\omega sin\phi}.$$ Now I would guess the mistake is in the very last calculation where $N=...$ My thinking was: in a half period the pendelum moves $\delta x'$ from its original plane, so in a full period it moves $2\delta x'$ and if it comes back to the start it moved $2\pi A$ (perpendicular to its 'normal' path).

Comment: If one  measures time in days, then Ωt = 2π and  the pendulum rotates by an angle of −2π sin(φ) during one day  where phi is the latitude of the place and omega is the earths angular velocity.i do not know what you intend to designate by N.

Comment: $N$ should be the number of oscillations / full turn. So after $t_0=2N\pi/\Omega$ the pendelum should be back in the $y'z'$ plane.

Comment: In that case if  t(0) is one day then N=1 .....will it be correct?

Comment: What do you mean? With $N$ I've ment the number of oscillation needed, s.t. the pendulum is oscillating in it's starting plane again.
My question was where my calculation went wrong, as I've read the correct (approximate) answer should be $N=\Omega/(\omega sin\phi)$

Comment: @hansl-well i used your equation ...  if your t(0) is one day then multiplied by angular velocity Omega  it will be 2.Pi and on the right hand you have 2.N.pi so N comes out to be unity.....so  some problem with your definition of N may be there /or i am wrong in interpreting your definition!

Comment: At middle latitudes, a Foucault pendulum takes longer than 24 hours to go around once [more exactly, it takes 24hr x sin(latitude), so in Columbus, it takes 37.3 hours. Foucault pendulums don't swing around at the Equator].

Comment: $\omega\neq\Omega$, $\Omega$ is the "angular velocity"  of the pendulum, the pendulum swings in the $K'$ frame, per assumption, $y'=Acos(\Omega t)$, while $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the earth

Comment: At the equator $sin\phi$ gets zero, so $N\rightarrow\infty$, which says, that it wont swing at the equator.

Comment: So your N will depend on the time period of pendulum you are using!

Comment: Yes! So my calculated $N$ is dependent on the time period of the pendulum! I edited the Question, as I missed to write a $\sin\Omega t$ in the expression for $\ddot{x'}(t)$.